# HTML form post to node.js file keeps loading

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express

I'm trying to do a simple form submission on my server that posts some contact information. I receive the information successfully on my node.js file that runs the server, but after I click submit the page tries to load action page and eventually fails.

HTML

```
<form id = "form" action="/", method = "post">
....
<button type="submit" form="form" value="Submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Node.js

```
app.post('/', function(req, res) {
.......
```

I'm using express to display static html and image files, and i'm connecting to localhost:8080/MyWebsite.html. But after I click the submit button I'm redirected unsuccessfully to localhost:8080, where chrome says "this site cannot be reached". Can someone explain to me exactly what's going on here, and how I can simply submit the form and stay on the page without any other issues?

Comment: What does the rest of the function you pass to `post()` look like? Where is the code in which you describe the response?

Answer (score 1):

You need to serve a response to the request.

If you want to stay on the page, you should serve a `204 No Content` response.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should add a path for app.post, So you could try:
HTML

```
<form id = "form" action="/process_post", method = "post">
....
<button type="submit" form="form" value="Submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

node.js

```
app.post('/process_post', function(req, res) {
.......
```

Answer (score -1):

Based on this line where you said:

***"but after I click submit the page tries to load action page and eventually fails."***

What you have to do is, you have to tell the page that the default functionality of the "submit" button wont be used, instead you will submit another way. Based on what you said, when you submit the form, it is trying to load whatever you put in the action field.

do the following.

```
$('#form').submit(functions(evt){
     evt.preventDefault();

    $.post('put here the link to the api or route that handles the post here'){
        //the code you are submitting to the route here
    }
});
```

Above, "evt.preventDefault()" stops your form from trying to submit using its default method.

Hope this helps.